# How to find out if monitor is Widescreen or Standard screen?

Tags: javascript, php, css

How can I tell using PHP, CSS or javascript if a monitor is standard (square) or widescreen?

Comment: Did you try in any of those languages already? What was your attempt?

Comment: the question here is "why"?

Comment: I've never seen a monitor with a square resolution, so I doubt that one could be considered "standard".

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answers your question. You could try doing this is Javascript. First, find a common denominator for your width and height:

```
function commonDenom (width, height) {
        return (height == 0) ? width : commonDenom (height, width % height);
}
```

Then plug in your screen width and height, and then get your aspect ratio:

```
var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
var d = commonDenom(w,h);
var ratio = w/d + ":" + h/d;
```

From there I guess you could match strings. Hope that helps